# creating a deep copy of a Reference Class: doesn't work on list fields?

Tags: r, list, object, reference

I am trying to copy an instance of a reference class (`foo`) which contains a list field. The list field contains instances of another class (`bar`). When copying the `foo` instance using the `$copy()` method the instances of the lists aren't copied and keep referring to the same object. The code below illustrates the problem. Is there a way around this? How can I do a true deep copy?

```
bar<-setRefClass("bar", fields = list(name = "character"))
foo<-setRefClass("foo", fields = list(tcp_vector = "list"))


x1<-foo()
x1$tcp_vector <- list(bar(name = "test1"))

x1$tcp_vector[[1]]$name # equals "test1"

x2 <- x1$copy()

x2$tcp_vector[[1]]$name # equals "test1"

x2$tcp_vector[[1]]$name <- "test2"  # set to "test2"

x2$tcp_vector[[1]]$name # equals "test2"

x1$tcp_vector[[1]]$name # also equals "test2"??
```

Comment: no clue about ref classes and if copy is implemented properly automatically, but you could just overwrite it with something like `copy=new("MicroPlate")
  listOldVars=ls(envir=self@.data, all.names=T)
  for(i in listOldVars){
    copy@.data[[i]]=self@.data[[i]]
  }
  return(copy)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `copy` method actually copies only `ReferenceClass` objects. Your `foo` class has just one field which is a `list`, and "normal" fields are not copied. This works:

```
bar<-setRefClass("bar", fields = list(name = "character"))
foo<-setRefClass("foo", fields = list(tcp_vector = "bar"))
x1<-foo()
x1$tcp_vector <- bar(name = "test1")
x1$tcp_vector$name # equals "test1"
x2 <- x1$copy()

x2$tcp_vector$name # equals "test1"

x2$tcp_vector$name <- "test2"  # set to "test2"

x2$tcp_vector$name # equals "test2"
x1$tcp_vector$name # equals "test"
```

See the help `?setRefClass` for details. If you want to keep the `foo` class defined as in the OP, I guess you have to manually copy any `bar` object before creating a copy of `x1`.